# Type cast error '__Pyx_memviewslice' to 'double *' Cython, what's the equivalent? MKL function prange code

Tags: python, numpy, cython, intel-mkl, typed-memory-views

I wrote a Cython program calling Intel MKL for matrix multiplication, with the purpose of making it parallel.  It was based on an old SO post linking to BLAS and used a bunch of Cython methods I've never seen, but got it working and it was much slower than NumPy (also linked to MKL).  In order to speed it up, I used the typical Memoryview format (it was using `ndarray` `np.float64_t` datatype for a couple operations).  But now it no longer works using `double[::1]` Memoryviews.  Here's the error generated:
    `'type cast': cannot convert from '__Pyx_memviewslice' to 'double *'`

And as a result of the type cast not working, the MKL function only sees 3 of 5 arguments:
    `error C2660: 'cblas_ddot': function does not take 3 arguments`

Here is the .PYX code:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
from cython cimport view
from cython.parallel cimport prange     #this is your OpenMP portion
from openmp cimport omp_get_max_threads #only used for getting the max # of threads on the machine 

cdef extern from "mkl_cblas.h" nogil: #import a function from Intel's MKL library
    double ddot "cblas_ddot"(int N,
                             double *X, 
                             int incX,
                             double *Y, 
                             int incY)

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
cpdef matmult(double[:,::1] A, double[:,::1] B):
    cdef int Ashape0=A.shape[0], Ashape1=A.shape[1], Bshape0=B.shape[0], Bshape1=B.shape[1], Arowshape0=A[0,:].shape[0] #these are defined here as they aren't allowed in a prange loop

    if Ashape1 != Bshape1:
        raise TypeError('Inner dimensions are not consistent!')

    cdef int i, j
    cdef double[:,::1] out = np.zeros((Ashape0, Bshape1))
    cdef double[::1] A_row = np.zeros(Ashape0)
    cdef double[:] B_col = np.zeros(Bshape1) #no idea why this is not allowed to be [::1]
    cdef int Arowstrides = A_row.strides[0] // sizeof(double)
    cdef int Bcolstrides = B_col.strides[0] // sizeof(double)
    cdef int maxthreads = omp_get_max_threads()

    for i in prange(Ashape0, nogil=True, num_threads=maxthreads, schedule='static'): # to use all cores

        A_row = A[i,:]
        for j in range(Bshape1):
            B_col = B[:,j]
            out[i,j] = ddot(Arowshape0, #call the imported Intel MKL library
                            <double*>A_row,
                            Arowstrides, 
                            <double*>B_col,
                            Bcolstrides) 

return np.asarray(out)
```

I'm sure this is easy for someone on SO to point out.  And please advise if you see where improvement can be made - this was hacked and chopped together and I don't think the i / j loops are even needed.  The cleanest example around: https://gist.github.com/JonathanRaiman/f2ce5331750da7b2d4e9 which I finally compiled is actually much faster (2x) but gives no results so I'll put that in another post (here: [Calling BLAS / LAPACK directly using the SciPy interface and Cython - also how to add MKL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710838/calling-blas-lapack-directly-using-the-scipy-interface-and-cython-also-how-t?noredirect=1&lq=1))

Much appreciated.

Comment: MKL's dgemm function does matrix multiplication and is multi-threaded

Comment: @user7138814 I saw that as well.  I saw your comment on my other Cython post - apparently I could use the same pointer based approach instead of the above???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a pointer from a memoryview you need to take the address of the first element

```
ddot(Arowshape0, #call the imported Intel MKL library
                        &A_row[0],
                        Arowstrides, 
                        &B_col[0],
                        Bcolstrides)
```

Comment: Are you saying then as well by passing the pointer I can get rid of all the loops above? That would be perfect.

Comment: I don't think so - you need the loops to make `A_row` and `B_col`. It's possible that some function other than `ddot` can do the whole thing though.

Comment: Thanks I'm really just building out my Cython toolkit.

Comment: So the memoryview pointer on a `double[:,::1] myarray` is likewise `&myarray[0,0]` I seem to have figured out... if you have a chance to confirm.

Comment: Thanks @DavidW for confirming, I got more code working with `memset` instead of NP..zeros